# How can C# look return an XML node with a specific element value?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

A commercial application uses XML to hold a list of variables it uses. I do not have control over the format of the XML. I can use any version of `.Net`.

Trying to write simpler code to assign a `UserVar` node to an object I've created. Right now I locate the node of the section of UserVars which contains all of the individual `UserVars`, iterate through each `UserVar` looking for the element "Name" and then see if it matches my desired variable name.

For example I want the variable "Changed" I will get an `AcmeVar` object (my creation) with the properties `Name` and `Width` set to "Changed" and 1. But I have to manually iterate through the code.

Seems like I'm doing this the hard way. Ideally I'd love to use Linq to return a `UserVar` node that has the matching element Name. The similar questions on Stackoverflow don't follow a similar pattern or at least not from what I can see. Not all variables use all of the element types.

Sample: XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application>
  <Vars>
    <UserVars>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Quantity"</Name>
        <Width>4</Width>
        <VarValue>"1"</VarValue>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Printers"</Name>
        <Width>255</Width>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Changed"</Name>
        <Width>1</Width>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Weight"</Name>
        <VarValue>"450.1"</VarValue>
      </UserVar>
    </UserVars>
  </Vars>
</Application>
```

Current Code:

```
public static bool GetVariable(string xmlDocNm, string varName, out AcmeVariable acmeVar)
{
  // Returns true if found without error

  bool result = false;
  acmeVar = new AcmeVariable ();

  try {
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xmlDocNm);
    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

    // Compile a standard XPath expression
    XPathExpression expr;
    expr = nav.Compile(AcmeConst.XPathInternalVariable);
    XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

    // Iterate on the node set
    try {
      bool variableFound;
      bool skipNode;

      char[] CharsToTrim = { '\"' }; // 
      while (iterator.MoveNext()) {
        variableFound = false;
        skipNode = false;
        XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
        if (nav2.MoveToFirstChild()) {
          // nav2 points to the first element in an UserVar Node
          acmeVar = new AcmeVariable ();               //Start with a fresh Acme Variable

          if (nav2.LocalName == AcmeConst.AttrName) {
            variableFound = true;
            skipNode = nav2.Value.Trim(CharsToTrim) != varName;
          }
          if (!skipNode) {
            AssignXMLNavNodetoAcmeVar(nav2, acmeVar);
            while (nav2.MoveToNext() && !skipNode) {
              if (nav2.LocalName == AcmeConst.AttrName) {
                variableFound = true;
                skipNode = nav2.Value.Trim(CharsToTrim) != varName;
              }
              AssignXMLNavNodetoAcmeVar(nav2, acmeVar);
            }
          }
        }
        if (variableFound && !skipNode) {
          result = true;
          break; //We have found the variable and collected all elements
        }
        else {
          acmeVar = null;
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      acmeVar = null;
      result = false;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    acmeVar = null;
    result = false;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var queryValue = "Quantity";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"UserVars.xml");//This is your xml path value

var userVar = xDoc.Descendents("UserVar").Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value == queryValue )
                  .FirstOrDefault();

var name     = userVar.Element("Name").Value ?? string.Empty;
var width    = userVar.Element("Width").Value ?? string.Empty;
var varValue = userVar.Element("VarValue").Value ?? string.Empty;
```

I just want to make comment with your XML, especially in the part where `<Name>"Quantity"</Name>` element value were enclosed with `""`

But if you have no bound with the xml, you just need to escape those `"`. eg. `var queryValue = @""Quantity"";`

Comment: Concerning the quotes, yes that is the way they have the string values. The file is from a commercial product so I have to live with it.

Comment: @Rich Shealer I also found error with the build of your XML. See the element `UserVar` with an element `Name` value of `"Quantity". That should be `<Width>4</Width>`, not `<Width>4</Format>`

Comment: This basically works. If the Element doesn't exist I get an exception rather than the string.empty. Since I don't privide a path to the UserVar section this would not descriminate if there was a similer section of UserVar. Not a problem in this case, just looking to understand.

Comment: Yes - I'll fix it.  Happened when I was making a minimalist example.

Comment: Yup. Then if you want to handle exceptions, just remove the `??` operator.

Comment: I put the assignment in a separate routine and took care of it there. I tried to change your post Descendants is mispelled but it wants at least 6 characters.

Comment: Interesting that he has the same misspelling I accidentally added before I edited it out... a few minutes before he initially posted his answer.

Comment: @Gjeltema I came here to post a new answer cause you used `x.Element.Name.Value` to access XElement Name value instead of doing it with `x.Element("Name").Value` before you edit your answer. xD

Comment: So you took my answer and copied it (with my old spelling error) and did a minor correction (which I edited in the correction at the same time or before you posted), rather than just pointing out the minor syntax error on my answer.  Nice.

Comment: @Gjeltema did I say so? I won't copy a dumb-ass code where exception was never handled xD

Comment: Sorry to see the conflict between the answers. I'm going with this answer because it had both pieces the XElement selection and then how to assign data using it. It would have taken me awhile before I sorted that out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your key is Name, and all nodes will contain that, then this should work:

```
string valImLookingFor = "\"Changed\"";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file"); // or XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var node = doc.Descendants("UserVar").Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value == valImLookingFor).First();
```

That should get you your node, then you can pull out the subnodes values you need.

Comment: This is similar to lexeRoy's answer. One thing about both of these answers is that it doesn't return an XmlNode. I'll need to see if I can use the Xelement that is returned to delete the existing node.

Comment: More accurately, his answer is similar to my answer as I posted earlier than him (sort by Oldest).  It doesn't return an XmlNode because that is the older way of doing XML in C#, prior to the introduction of Linq to Xml.  Yes, you can delete elements using XElement (much easier than you can with XmlNode).